# How to generate hundreds of dynamic Html in c# MVC?

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller, windows-services

I am working with MVC C#. My manager asked me to create a marketing part in our admin panel.

For sending emails I made a table by name "Notifications". After creating email body, for specific customer by rendering a View with desired model, I insert the email content and address as a row in Notification table. After that a windows service which is running on server,Will automatically send that email. Up to here everything works fine.

```
string html = this.RenderViewToString("CustomerEmailView", customerModel);
```

But My problem arises when I have to **generate emails** for 6000 customers. Besides I have to use MVC to generate the HTML with `RenderViewTostring()` instead of `String.Replace()`, and also my server gets timed out when generating less amount!

What is the best way to generate these amount of emails? What's more, I do not have one single email template. Depends on where you are in the admin panel, specific

Comment: As you are trying to insert bulk of data so try BULK INSERT this is the reason your server timeout.

Comment: I have no problem with insert. my problem is for rendering and populating html!

Comment: check if your mail server has no maximum outbox restriction, like gmail or free zoho mail would not let you do it, our organization use a service like MailChimp for that.